# Dropdown hint is not visible in React code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown, placeholder, contentplaceholder

I have a TagPicker which extends component.
This is how I render the Dropdown:

```
render() {
const { options, value, disabled, t } = this.props;
const trigger = <Icon name="tags" className="iconTagPicker" />;
return (
  <Dropdown
    trigger={trigger}
    allowAdditions
    disabled={disabled}
    fluid
    multiple
    onAddItem={this.newTag}
    onChange={this.onChange}
    options={options}
    placeholder="Hello"
    search
    selection
    selectOnBlur={false}
    value={value}
    className="tagPicker"
  />
);
}
}
```

As you can see the placeholder is there, but even so, nothing is visible. why?

This is how the html park looks like:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/39260/829560/QHJNvvzMSUziV9m/upload.png
```

If I remove the trigger, I will have the placeholder, but no icon, how can I make it so that the icon will not make the placeholder go away?

DropDown: https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown#dropdown-example-icon

Comment: We don't have enough information! No way to tell what's happening if we don't know what Dropdown does... Also, why the contentplaceholder tag? It's a ASP.NET related tag

Comment: Sorry mate, I'm fairly knew to react, all projects that I saw use semantic-ui-react. So assumed this is pretty standard. But I did manage to fix it, after I found their documentation, and went through all the cases.

Comment: Happy you managed to solve it! If I were you, next time I'd put semantic-ui in the tags and everyone will know immediately where to look for, no need to actually link to the docs. Ps: don't hold a grudge, it wasn't me who downvoted :)

Comment: I'm not, I was just explaining :p Yes, definitely will do that the next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing this: `trigger={trigger}` into `icon={trigger}` worked. Was not aware that a icon trigger will make the placeholder disappear.